# Rotina para limpar checkbox de listview C#

Tags: c#

Criei uma pequena rotina para limpar os checkbox que estão no meu listview no C# windows forms. Porém essa rotina não esta desmarcando os mesmos. Gostaria de saber se escrevi algo errado ou o motivo de não funcionar. Código:

```
    private void limpacheck()
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lsvRecebeGrupoLayout.CheckedItems)
        {
            item.Checked = false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere CheckedItems para Items

```
private void limpacheck()
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lsvRecebeGrupoLayout.Items)
    {
        item.Checked = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou brother, porém ele limpou todas as linhas que tem marcação na check. Seria possível manter as informações das linhas e desmarcar só a check?

Comment: Isso já não sei, desculpe

Comment: Tudo bem rs, resolveu o problema que é o mais importante. Valeu mesmo!